# MySQL insert date value depending on another date value - trigger

Tags: mysql, date, triggers

I have a table with time planifications: eg: one month, 3 month, 6 month
I want to link my users with this table

I want to create a trigger that updates my finalisation date depending on the start date and the planification table

```
> CREATE TRIGGER `sum_fin`  BEFORE INSERT ON `planificare_leg`  FOR EACH
> ROW  BEGIN
>     IF NEW.`data_final` IS NULL THEN
>         SET NEW.data_final = 
> (SELECT  DATE_ADD(`data_start`,INTERVAL `valoare_durata` `fel_durata` ) as data_fin
> FROM v_users_planificare
> where codtimp = NEW.codtimp and user_id = NEW.user_id) ;
>     END IF; 
>     END;
```

valoare_durata is an integer field that contains the number of mounts. eg: for the plan 3 month, valoare_durata = 3 and fel_durata = MONTH

the sql returns this error:

`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fel_durata ) as data_fin FROM v_users_planificare where codtimp = NEW.codtimp an' at line 6`

i created a test to see what happens:

> update planificare_leg l join v_users_planificare  plan on
>   plan.user_id = l.user_id and plan.codtimp = l.codtimp set activ = 1
>   where DATE_ADD(`data_start`,INTERVAL 1 MONTH) <= NOW() and data_start >= NOW()

works

but

> update planificare_leg l join v_users_planificare  plan on
>   plan.user_id = l.user_id and plan.codtimp = l.codtimp set activ = 1
>   where DATE_ADD(`data_start`,INTERVAL `valoare_durata` `fel_durata`) <=
>   NOW() and data_start >= NOW()

doesn't work

Comment: Not sure if this applies to MySql, but in SQL Server the single quotes indicate a string. There, if you want to identify a field name would use the double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, missing a paren

```
SET NEW.data_final = (SELECT  DATE_ADD(`data_start`,INTERVAL `valoare_durata` `fel_durata` )) as data_fin FROM v_users_planificare
                                                                                            ^
```

Comment: no. the select is from v_users_planificare and  DATE_ADD(`data_start`,INTERVAL `valoare_durata` `fel_durata` ) is as data_fin

Comment: Darn, stumped. Is the Type Value (fel_durata) allowed to be an expression rather than a literal (DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, ...)?

Comment: I don't know. how do i do that?

Comment: Find out what the uti is and the writ it like "DATE_ADD(data_start,INTERVAL valoare_durata DAY). See Type Value at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp